# Transparent background in the bottom bar with rounded corners

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display content using a bottom bar with rounded edges. I'm trying to set it up so that the content doesn't go behind the bottom bar.

For this I use padding values ​​and everything is fine, but when using "padding values" parameter a white background appears.

How can I make it transparent with padding?

[image]

**Bottom bar:**

```
    fun BottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavigationBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50.dp, 25.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp))
    ) {
        screens.forEach { screen ->
            AddItem(
                screen = screen,
                currentDestination = currentDestination,
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Scaffold:**

```
Scaffold(
   containerColor = Color.Transparent,
   bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }
) { paddingValues -> 
    Column(
         modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues )
) {
     HomeNavGraph(navController = navController, mainViewModel)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share BottomBAr code?

Answer (score 0):

It is transparent, it shows the color of whatever composable is under the `Scaffold`, because it has `containerColor = Color.Transparent`.

Your could either change the `Scaffold`'s `containerColor` or set color of the composable containing the `Scaffold`.

Alternatively, instead of applying `paddingValues` to the whole content, you can use `paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding()` to add spacing at the bottom of your content. For example:

```
Scaffold(
    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
    bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }
) { paddingValues ->
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            items(50) { Text(text = "Item $it") }
            item {
                Spacer(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding())
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change the color from transparent to another, then when scrolling through the page it will be visible that the elements will abut this colored border. In this case, there is no point in making rounded edges. And they are needed

Comment: I thought your goal was to make that content doesn't go behind the bottom bar. If you set `paddingValues` your content won't be visible behind bottom bar's rounded corners, and it's not because the corners aren't transparent. @GeorgeKusenkov

Comment: In order for the screen elements to be displayed correctly, I add padding, but in this case a white background appears in the corners of the bottombar and I don’t know how to make it transparent

Comment: So you want your content go behind the bottom bar and be visible around the rounded corners when scrolling, but initially it must be above it? @GeorgeKusenkov

Comment: that's right. I use a lazy column and when I scroll to the end of the screen there should be padding

Comment: That's a different problem, I updated my answer with a possible solution. @GeorgeKusenkov

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already thought about doing this, but I wanted to choose a more concise solution. Because this is a common scaffold for navgraph and I thought that padding valuse on the scaffold was a good solution, but I didn't think I would run into difficulties. You'll have to fill out Spacer manually =)

Comment: I don't think there is a way around it. You either apply padding to the whole content (easy, but not your case) or figure out a way to apply it partially. @GeorgeKusenkov